# Strange Error -java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Tags: java, android, xml

When i move from Activity A to B  app crashes and i get 2 lines of log posted below
the app works fine but i cannot go to Activity B as it gives error

```
AndroidRuntime(2438):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
AndroidRuntime(2438):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

how can i fix this problem or know what is happening?

Activity B

```
       public class B extends Activity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lay_b);
         }}
```

Comment: @Metalhead1247 show your code snippets and mention for which cases it is throwing exception

Comment: @RohitJain there is no code in the activity just oncreate still throwing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved
 Error was from Activity A
  progressbar was never initialized

```
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
            if(progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
         }
```

which gave error  as **java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)** After propogating to ActivityB

Comment: If you posted the entire stack trace, or read it yourself, you would see further down `caused by.......NullPointerException` with the exact line where the exception was thrown.

Comment: @simon im not a newbie, there were only 2 lines of logs in logcat no null pointer Exceptions so had to post it here